# create update profile picture in jquery and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to perform functionality for `update profile picture` same like facebook update profile picture option.like when cursor hover over image user get the update profile picture div above on his picture and when user click on that div bootstrap model will be open that ask for the profile picture.

this is the code that i have done so far [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/e4pamhe2/6/)

```
<div class="col-sm-4">                              
    <img class="img-thumbnail" style="width:100%" src="<img src="bootstrap/assets/img/profiles/avatar2x.jpg'">
   <div class='picture-hover'>Update Profile Picture</div>
</div>
```

the problem that i encounter with this is `picture-hover` is not displaying on above the picture same as facebook.

2nd who can i display model for uploading picture when `picture-hover` is clicked.

Please point me into right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Bootstrap doesn't have its own Image Overlay, so it is not possible to build this up without writing some own code.

If you follow this following example I found with Google you can do an overlay like this:

http://www.bootply.com/90238

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Thumbnail Headline</h4>
                    <p>short thumbnail description</p>
                    <p><a href="" class="label label-danger" rel="tooltip" title="Zoom">Zoom</a>
                    <a href="" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" title="Download now">Download</a></p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/1/" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.thumbnail {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.caption {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background:rgba(66, 139, 202, 0.75);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:2%;
    display: none;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff !important;
    z-index:2;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
        }
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

[This is a very detailed explanation for the question you have asked. I hope this helps you in some way !](http://wsnippets.com/fancy-profile-image-upload-crop-jquery-ajax-php/)